# I am having difficulty in understanding the sentence

Tags: grammar, interpretation

**That he not busy being born is busy dying.**
—By Bob Dylan

Actual meaning of the sentence?

Comment: No 'meaning'; it's a song.

Comment: Because of initial "that", it's not a sentence - it's just a "clause". But what it *means* is that anyone who doesn't spend their lifetime "being born" (metaphorically, *improving* themselves) is effectively just passing time until they die (they're *decaying*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - maybe I'm being mischievous, or overthinking, but I can't help wondering why there can't be an equilibrium state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person who is not busy being born anymore, is a person who is busy dying. In other words, as soon as the hard work of being born is over, you start dying.

Comment: This answers the OP's question, which is about meaning, not syntax.  I don't know why it's downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The first "That" is a subordinator marking this as a content clause (as a whole it functions somewhat like a noun) and not an independent sentence.

Removing the subordination marker, we get a pronoun modified by a relative clause - that is rather rare and poetic.  "He not busy being born", literally "A person who is not busy being born".  Then "is" is the copulative verb, and the complement "busy dying".

You can form the adjective "busy" with a participle complement "busy working" Here it is "busy being born" and "busy dying" - which are more poetic.

As usual, lyrics are not typical of prosaic English.  Study lyrics to learn how to write lyrics, not as examples of normal English.